# How do I listen to Android's contacts launch activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to know when Android's contact launch activity is opened because my application opens after a call is finished and then the contact launch activity is opened after it meaning it will cover my app's activity leading to that I have to press "back" button to see my app.

That is, I want to open my app after contact launch activity has been opened.
All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the Android SDK. Sorry!